# when passing head of linked list to function.Why do we need to pass it by reference of reference such as in push(node* &head, int key)

Tags: c++

Printed out the address of head and &head:
head:0x603050
&head :0x7fffffffe4b8: what does this signify?

```
void push(node* &head,int key)// Inserts items at front of link list
{
    node* linkNode=new node(); //declares new node
    linkNode->data=key;
    if(head==NULL)             //if the link list is empty then create a new one.
    {
        linkNode->next=NULL;
        head=linkNode;   //1
    }
    else
    {
        linkNode->next=head;
        head=linkNode;
    }    
}
```

Main function where all other functions are called from
link list is 8,4,2
main function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    node* head=NULL;         //initializing head to NULL
    push(head,2);           //creating link list
    push(head,4);           //this requires &head
    push(head,8);           //link list is 8,4,2
    selectSort(head);        //this does not require &head
    reverse(head);          //this requires &head
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: > Printed out the address of head and &head: head:0x603050 &head :0x7fffffffe4b8: what does this signify? 0x603050 is a pointer to the first node which is in the heap, 0x7fffffffe4b8 is a pointer to head which is on the stack. In order to change the address in head, you need to change the address stored in 0x7fffffffe4b8.

Comment: you have to pass by reference if the function has to modify the argument passed. In `C`, we will have to pass by pointer to pointer. Eg: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a353d5761903768

Answer (score 4):

> Why do we need to pass it by reference of reference such as in push(node* &head, int key)

Otherwise it won't work to set the given `linkNode` as current `head`:

```
    if(head==NULL)             //if the link list is empty then create a new one.
    {
        linkNode->next=NULL;
        head=linkNode; // <- This statement changes the head variable passed from main()
    }
```

What you have is a reference to a pointer (`head`) that will be *'returned'* from the `push()` function, and set the `head` pointer passed from the caller correctly:

```
node* head=NULL;
push(head,2); // sets head to the node created for key '2'
```

---

Don't forget to `delete` all the `node` instances you have created with `new node();`. In a different context as you're showing, this might lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a "reference of reference"; it's a reference to a pointer.

It means that, once the pointer `head` has been set to point to the new element, within the function, *this change also affects the pointer you originally passed in to the function*.

---

```
selectSort(head);        //this does not require &head
```

It probably should do, actually, if the function performs a sort over all elements of the list.

---

```
reverse(head);          //this requires &head
```

After this call, `head` now points to the new head of the list. This would not be possible if you'd passed `head` by value.

**An alternative implementation might `return` the new head pointer, instead of using this "out parameter" convention.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason you must pass `head` to the `push` function is because your `push` function is expecting to modify the value of the `head` pointer.  If you don't pass it by reference, any changes to it will only be available within the function call.  For example, if it was not passed by reference, and you passed `head` (initialized to `NULL`), to the `push` function, a new item would be created, but your value for `head` would only be updated inside the function.  Once you left the function, it will still be `NULL` (because you passed the pointer by copy).

Note that this can go away if you create a linked list class instead of treating your nodes as a linked list themselves (that is, encapsulate the nodes under a list interface - which is what the standard library does).